# How can I get Chrome to launch and close "developer tools" on Mac (like Firebug with F12 & Ctrl+Shift+C)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firebug

How can I get Chrome to launch and close "developer tools" on Mac (like Firebug with <kbd>F12</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>)? It was so convenient in Firefox/Firebug to just hit <kbd>F12</kbd> followed by "toggle inspect mode" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and then hover my mouse over the different elements. I would love it if anyone else used to have this workflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For those that are still looking for ways to access Chrome's Developer Tools:

To access the developer tools, open a web page or web app in Google Chrome. Then take one of the following actions:

- Select the Wrench menu  at the top-right of your browser window, then select Tools -> Developer tools.
- Right-click on any page element and select Inspect element.
- On Windows and Linux, press

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open Developer Tools
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to open Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.
  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to toggle Inspect Element mode.
- On OS X, press

  - <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Option+Command+I) to open Developer Tools
  - <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (Option+Command+J) to open Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.
  - <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Control+Command+C) to toggle Inspect Element mode.

Source: http://code.google.com/intl/nl/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html

Comment: You have the key symbols mixed up... **⌘ = Command, ⌥ = Option**. See [Dan Rodney's List of Mac OS X Keyboard Shortcuts & Keystrokes](http://www.danrodney.com/mac/).

Comment: In newer  versions of Google Chrome, you can now use F12 to open developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Opens developer tools. I don't think you can toggle "inspect mode" (I found this looking for that)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, one thing I really loved about Firebug, hopefully it comes to Chrome (or I switch back to FF).

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac, I use:

`"Cmd" + "Option" + "I"` - To open/close Developer Tools

`"Cmd" + "Shift" + "C"` - Opens Inspect